# Writing \textg with bold letters

Tags: tipa

I'm using the package `tipa` and I'm trying to write `\textg` with bold letters. I tried `\textbf{\textg}` but it did not work.

Comment: i'm not a user of `tipa`, but it's my understanding that the glyph commands shouldn't be entered as math (surrounded by `$` signs), but within the scope of `\textipa{...}`.  (there are others here more qualified to answer, but they don't seem to be active just now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right, but now I want to know how can I write \textg with bold letters =(

Comment: this is what the manual says:  `{\fontseries{b}\selectfont \textipa{...}}`.

Comment: Is this question just about using `\textg` only (in bold letters) whereas any other symbol/character is not using `tipa` fonts? `\textbf{\textg}` provides a bold letter for me

Comment: I put \textbf{\textg} but this is how it looks 
http://puu.sh/oIHhn/3cdbbaf30b.png

Comment: Try `\textg \textbf{\textg}` and compare the two `g` characters.  I've got the impression from that linked image that it is **bold**

Comment: This is how it looks http://puu.sh/oIHVe/d726ecc2cb.png I used exactly \textg \textbf{\textg}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for demonstration purposes: `\textg` is not bold, `\textbf{\textg}` is bold:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}

\huge \textg \textbf{\textg}

\end{document}
```

[image]